# Write a function that takes an array by calling another function to return a value and store it on a new array

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with my code for this javascript exercise as follows:

/**

- In the function, accept an array, and call the callback on each element of the array
- the callback will return a value - use this value and store it in a new array
- for each iteration, the value returned from the callback, should replace the value in the previous array
- you should return the new array with the new value
- example:
- const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
- const newNumbers = map(numbers, (number) => {
- return number + 3;
- });
- console.log(newNumbers); // [4,5,6,7,8];
- @param {number[]} array
- @param {Function} callback
  */

//my javascript code//

```
function map(array, callback) {
  for (let newArray of array) {
    value(callback(newArray));
  }
  return value;
}
export default map;
```

Comment: What is the use of generating a new array (step 2) **and** changing the original one (step 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply push callback return into array and return that same array from your custom fucntion.

You can also modify original array using index.

```js
const customMap = (arr, callback) => {
  const finalArr = []
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    const res = callback(item)
    finalArr.push(res)
    arr[index] = res // This will modify original array
  })

  return finalArr
}


const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const newNumbers = customMap(numbers, (number) => {
  return number + 3;
});

console.log(newNumbers);
console.log(numbers);
```